# Cannot add Stack Exchange login

Tags: support

I've been using Word Press Open ID. I thought I'd add Stack Exchange login. It asks for my email address and password. Then it says it cannot find a Stack Exchange account with that email address. The email address is in my Stack Overflow account. I had already clicked to sync Stack Exchange with Stack Overflow. But Stack Exchange only shows the name and web site in the big box. Big box is a highly technical programming term. (See vol. II of Knuth.) I didn't spend much time on this, so it is quite possibly a mental problem on my part. I thought you'd like to know about it, though, because at a minimum it is a bit obscure.

Also... "possible bug" is possibly a bug.

- I click on my username
- I click on "my logins"
- I click on "Add More Logins"
- It says, "Click the logo to add another login to your account" so I click on "Log In with Stack Exchange"
- It says, "Sign in with your Stack Exchange Account"

I fail. **How do I create a new Stack Exchange login?**  I really don't care that much, it's for your info. I just thought it was a little obscure if not broken. I really like the sites, by the way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell based on your description, but I think you're confused about the account.

You must *create* a Stack Exchange login -- you do not automatically have one by virtue of merely existing as a user on, say, Stack Overflow.

For example in your case, you are using a WordPress login. There is no Stack Exchange login *until you create a new Stack Exchange login*.

edit: I see, the flow is a little weird here. Go to https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register and create an account in this specific case; we'll see what we can do to improve the flow.

Comment: hmm, I see what you mean. We'll have to add a create option in that path, most of the time these are new users adding their *first* set of credentials. So, for now, go to https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register and create your account, then follow the steps you outline.

Comment: One other "design consideration"...  When I login under my new Stack Exchange login (I tried this in SuperUser), it brings up a new xpda account with no history, etc. When I look under users, there are 2 xpda's, both with no reputation, one with a city-state. When I logout and back in with WordPress, the world is as it should be.

Comment: SU and SF have some special considerations because they are much older. I merged those accounts for you there. The "my login" wallet is stored at the network level, so it should be OK elsewhere.